# Android expandable list view with two Text views

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I am trying to create a custom expandable list view with two seperate text views. One textview needs to be aligned left and the other aligned right. Can anyone help me.

This is my layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
        android:text="@string/click"
        android:textColor="@color/Red" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my adapter class

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
            HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is my main activity

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment(){}
    TextView Username;
    TextView Acct, Paid, Email;
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
    List<String> horse;
    List<String> owner ;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

        // preparing list data
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Rider and Trainer Info");
        listDataHeader.add("Horse and Owner Info");

        // Adding child data
        horse = new ArrayList<String>();
        horse.add("horse");

        owner = new ArrayList<String>();




        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), horse); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), owner);

        Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(context, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        final GlobalClass globalVariable = (GlobalClass) getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        String Name = globalVariable.getName();
        String acct = globalVariable.getUsersid();
        String paid = globalVariable.getPaid();
        String email = globalVariable.getEmail();

        Username = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        Acct = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        Paid = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        Email = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        Username.setText("Username: "+ Name);
        Acct.setText("Acct # "+ acct);
        Paid.setText("Expired On: "+ paid);
        Email.setText("Email: " + email);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I want the output layout to look like this on each line.

Sample text             Date

Comment: I know how to align the text view. but how can i programatically. load the listview with arrays that updates both textview.

Comment: Sorry, I think I don’t understand you. Indeed, I don’t think understand the question. Looking at your code, you already are updating one TextView. Why don’t you update the other in the same way? 

TextView date = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(date);

        date.setText(childText);

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. I added that line of code. But it is not working im pretty sure I have to add more than that one linebof code. But im mot sure its wher  to add the other code.

Answer (score 1):

Just find another view from your layout

```
    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        TextView lblListDate = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListDate);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(date);

        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="lblListItem"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I know how to align the text view. but how can i programatically. load the listview with arrays that updates both textview.

Answer (score 0):

If you instead use a RelativeLayout. You can align the TextViews to the left/right using the layout_align(left/right) xml property.

Like this

```
android:layout_alignRight = "true"
```

Comment: I know how to align the text view. but how can i programatically. load the listview with arrays that updates both textview.